# Apache commons-mail HtmlEmail with attachment: html is attached as noname.html in Gmail

Tags: java, gmail, html-email, sap-commerce-cloud, apache-commons-email

I use the apache commons-mail (v1.3.2) to send an order confirmation e-mail with a PDF as attachment.
The e-mail displays without problems in outlook (both web and desktop) but when I send to my gmail account, the content of the mail is empty and the Html content is attached in a separate file "noname.html".

My code:

```
       // Create mail instance using commons-mail and the hybris MailUtility class.
        HtmlEmail htmlEmail = (HtmlEmail) MailUtils.getPreConfiguredEmail(); // creates a mail instance with set mail
        htmlEmail.setCharset("UTF-8");
        htmlEmail.setHtmlMsg("this is <b>html text</b>);

        // Part two is attachment
            DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(mailAttachment.getData(), "application/pdf");
            htmlEmail.attach(ds, "attach.pdf", "generalconditions", EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
        }

        //send mail
        htmlEmail.send();
```

At first, this issue occured also in outlook but I fixed this by switching from commons-mail v1.1 to v1.3.2.
Still not fixed for gmail though...

Comment: Because the getPreconfiguredEmail() method is from the Hybris MailUtils class.I thought it would be useful to add the tag, just in case it would be a known hybris issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setPath(pdfFile.getPath());
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
```

Then you attach it to the email like this :

```
htmlEmail.attach(attachment);
```

Comment: Here are a few examples : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html